# CORS issue: GET call to Dropbox auth using AJAX from Bootstrap modal not working

Tags: jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap-3, cors, dropbox-api

I am building an app with Dropbox access, and the `authorization` step is returning `No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8082' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 400.`

The app is in HTML/JQuery/Bootstrap/Cordova.

According to the [documentation](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http/documentation), I should be able to send a `simple cross-site request` using `contentType: 'text/plain; charset=dropbox-cors-hack'`, but am getting the above error.

The `client_id` matches what is in my Dropbox/myapp `App key`.
The `redirect_uri` matches what is in my Dropbox/myapp `Redirect URIs`.

Here is my code:

```
var client_id =         'matchesCodeInDropboxAppRegistration';
var response_type =     'token';
var redirect_uri =  'https://www.dropbox.com/1/oauth2/redirect_receiver';
//var csrfToken =   generateCSRFToken();
var csrfToken =     'some_val'; // in process
var data =      'response_type=' + response_type + '&client_id=' + client_id + '&redirect_uri=' + redirect_uri + '&state=' + csrfToken + '&reject_cors_preflight=true';

$.ajax( {

    method: 'GET',
    url: 'https://www.dropbox.com/1/oauth2/authorize?' + data,
    contentType: 'text/plain; charset=dropbox-cors-hack',

    success: function( html ) {

        $( "#db-modal-body" ).html( html );
    },

    error: function( jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown ) {

        console.log( "AdminDBAuthView: db_connect: fail:", textStatus, errorThrown, jqXHR );
    }
} );

$( "#dropbox-connect" ).modal( "toggle" );
```

BTW, I tried this, and got the same result:

```
$( "#dropbox-connect" ).modal( {
    remote: 'https://www.dropbox.com/1/oauth2/authorize?' + data,
    show: true
} );
```

backbone.js v1.3.3 / 
underscore.js v1.8.3 / 
bootstrap v3.3.6 / 
JQuery v2.2.4 / 
cordova v6.1.1 / 
Node 5.10.1 / npm v3.8.6

I've been banging away at this for a while, so any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: Which browser you using?

Comment: Seems like more of an issue with using AJAX to access an HTTPS resource when loading your page over HTTP, that's most likely the problem.

Comment: @Jordan I've been working in Chrome

Comment: @Jordan: Shouldn't I get a `mixed content` type error then? I am getting a `XMLHttpRequest` error.

Answer (score 0):

You're attempting to access www.dropbox.com/1/oauth2/authorize via an AJAX call, but this is actually a web page the user should access directly in their browser.

The [documentation for /oauth2/authorize says](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http/documentation#authorization):

> This isn't an API call—it's the web page that lets the user sign in to Dropbox and authorize your app.

As such, it doesn't allow CORS.

You can find more information on the OAuth app authorization flow here:

https://www.dropbox.com/developers/reference/oauth-guide

Comment: Correct. I started with
`$( "#dropbox-connect" ).modal( {
    remote: 'https://www.dropbox.com/1/oauth2/authorize?' + data,
    show: true
} );`
but no love. 
But it may be an issue loading a secure page into a bootstrap modal. I'll look into it.

Answer (score 0):

If you check the simple request to [redirect reciver for example](https://www.dropbox.com/1/oauth2/redirect_receiver) you will see that:

```
content-security-policy:default-src 'none' ; worker-src blob: ; style-src https://* 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' ; connect-src https://* ws://127.0.0.1:*/ws ; child-src blob: ; img-src https://* data: blob: ; frame-src https://* carousel://* dbapi-6://* dbapi-7://* dbapi-8://* itms-apps://* itms-appss://* ; object-src https://cfl.dropboxstatic.com/static/ https://www.dropboxstatic.com/static/ 'self' https://flash.dropboxstatic.com https://swf.dropboxstatic.com https://dbxlocal.dropboxstatic.com ; media-src https://* blob: ; font-src https://* data: ; script-src 'unsafe-eval' https://www.dropbox.com/static/javascript/ https://www.dropbox.com/static/api/ https://cfl.dropboxstatic.com/static/javascript/ https://www.dropboxstatic.com/static/javascript/ https://cfl.dropboxstatic.com/static/api/ https://www.dropboxstatic.com/static/api/ https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/ 'unsafe-inline'  'nonce-oewijAWrBU8hHBjx84Ta' ;
```

and no mentions about localhost but mentioning about `connect-src https://* ws://127.0.0.1`

Try change your URL to http://127.0.0.1